# Unable to locate adb

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, adb, platform-tools

Can't run any android app because it is unable to locate adb.
[I found some answers says that message will show because SDK platform-tools is not installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbb8h.png)

When I try to update it, it stops at this point
[The point where the updating stops](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwj4O.png)

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First check your SDK location.
**File -> Project Structure -> SDK Location**.
Then choose your SDK. After that the ADB should be located in the folder of your SDK: **Android/SDK/platform-tools/adb**.
You can always download the platform-tools from Android and place the folder in your SDK. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run Android studio " run as administrator", then update Android SDK it not fails.

For run Android Studio As Administrator Right click on the android-studio and click "Run As Administrator".

Answer (score 0):

this error is basically because Adb.exe is missing in the studio path.you can simply add it to the path.
or check your anti-virus quarantined maybe it has adb. So simply go to the virus chest and add adb to the list of antivirus exclusions.It worked perfectly with me.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

1. open Studio settings --> System settings --> Android SDK --> select SDK tool tab --> select "Android SDK platform tool" and install
2. Check your antivirus quarantine items. Maybe anti-virus is blocking adb file.
3. Restart your phone and again start Developer options and then enable USB Debugging.

Answer (score 0):

For those who tried everything else and still can't make it work. Please check if you are running another emulation.

I got this obscure problem and couldn't resolve it no matter what I tried. It turns out it simply was because I was running virtualbox on another desktop and I wasn't aware of that. The error is totally misleading. I was using Ubuntu 16.04. After I shut down the other virtual machine, Android emulator started without any problem. Even though I still have this error message.

Answer (score 0):

The system and user environment path in your windows is not properly set.

Goto properties of This PC > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables > Path > then put the path file location.